# Java: How to test for EOF on an InputStream without blocking?

Tags: java, nonblocking, eof

I want to do something like this:

```
// Implement an interruptible read
for(;;) {
  if (input.available() > 0)
    buffer.append(input.read());
  else if (input.eof())
    return buffer;
  else
    Thread.sleep(250);
}
```

If I didn't care about blocking, I would have done this:

```
for(;;) {
  c = input.read();
  if (c != -1)
    buffer.append(c);
  return buffer;
}
```

But I do care, so I need to use available(), so how can I determine EOF?

Comment: Why not do the latter in a separate thread?

Comment: to reiterate comments made elsewhere: whatever your problem, `available()` is not the solution.  it is basically a useless method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the `NIO` library instead, as that provides non-blocking IO (as the name suggests). There's an Oracle blog post about IO vs NIO: [Here](http://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio).

Alternatively there are some code examples provided [Here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/cancel.html) about setting timeout parameters on the read from an `InputStream`

Comment: NIO is the way to go. I would not trust input.available(), for example, if you were reading something on a network file system you might not get the answer you're expecting.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm working with a pretty large package; switching from io to nio isn't something I can undertake lightly.  I will look into using timeout parameters instead, though.

Comment: Adding a timeout to the socket stream seems to be my best bet, although I'll still take a serious look at using nio.  Such a shame that reads are not interruptible.

Comment: The solution in the link you provided seems to be flawed. When the stream is terminated, available() returns 0. That means that the implementation always hits the timeout...
I don't think we can rely on available() to support a timeout on a generic input stream. I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: linking away from stackoverflow is totally not OK: if such page dies, like in this case, the answer is worthless.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in socket channels if you are concerned with not blocking. Channels can be found in the java.nio package. Specifically you may be interested in `ReadableByteChannel` interface and the classes that implement it.

You'd use channels something like this.

```
SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8000));

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

while(channel.read(buffer) != -1) { 
// if -1 is returned then stream has been closed and loop should exit
    if (buffer.remaining() == 0) {
        // buffer is full, you might want to consume some of the data in buffer
        // or allocate a larger buffer before continuing
    }
    // we have now just read as much was available on the socket channel. Any
    // immediate  attempts to read from the channel again will result in the 
    // read method returning immediately.
    // Hence try to do something useful with the data before reading again
}

// channel is now closed
```